# Conditional col-md-push-X and col-md-X classes in Razor code (using MVC)

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have the following list to display entries in an hierarchical way. If `ParentEntryId` is null, then the entry is a main entry, otherwise it is a sub-entry. Also, there is `Depth` property of entry. If Depth=0, than the entry is a main entry, if Depth=1, then the entry is the first descendent of the main entry, and so forth.

Here is the code that iterates the entry records retrieved from the database, and calls the _EntryItemView.cshtml view for each Entry record.

```
foreach (var entry in Model.Entries)
{
    if (entry.ParentEntryId == null)
    {         
         @Html.Partial("~/Views/Entry/_EntryItemView.cshtml", entry)
         foreach (var subentry in Model.Entries.Where(e => e.ParentEntryId == entry.EntryId))
         {                                  
              @Html.Partial("~/Views/Entry/_EntryItemView.cshtml", entry)
         }
    }
}
```

Here is the _EntryitemView.cshtml:

```
<div class="col-md-12 small list-group main-entry entry-item-view">
</div>
```

The `col-md-12` class for the div should be only when it is a main entry (with Depth=0). However, when the Depth=1, I want to have `col-md-push-1 col-md-11`

```
<div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-11 small list-group main-entry entry-item-view">
</div>
```

and if the Depth=2 I want to have `col-md-push-2 col-md-10`, so forth.

Is there a way to automatize this ? I wonder if this is doable via Razor? Or do I need to use Jquery?

Comment: One option would be to include the CSS classes as part of your view model and apply the CSS classes from the view model directly in the `_EntryItemView` view.

Comment: @BabakNaffas what kind of css class? Could you please elaborate a little bit more?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below in your `_EntryItemView.cshtml`

```
@if(Model.Depth == 0)
{
    <div class="col-md-12 small list-group main-entry entry-item-view">
    </div>
}
else if(Model.Depth == 1)
{
    <div class="col-md-push-1 col-md-11 small list-group main-entry entry-item-view">
    </div>
}
else if(Model.Depth == 2)
{
    <div class="col-md-push-2 col-md-10 small list-group main-entry entry-item-view">
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to automatize this?